# Swift CustomNavigationController navigationItem Not Work

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

AppDelegate

```
let navigationController = ExampleNavigationController.init(rootViewController: tabBarController)
tabBarController.title = "Modda"
self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
```

ExampleNavigationController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 250/255.0, green: 250/255.0, blue: 250/255.0, alpha: 0.8)
    self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.init(red: 44/255.0, green: 49/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1.0), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)]
    self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 44/255.0, green: 49/255.0, blue: 64/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    self.navigationItem.title = "Modda"

    //Left Item Button
    let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menu"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    //button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(SSASideMenu.presentLeftMenuViewController), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
}
```

In this class `navigationItem.title` and `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` not work.

Also,

I tried to set on viewcontroller

```
class HomeController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Left Item Button
        let button = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
        button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "menu"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        //button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(SSASideMenu.presentLeftMenuViewController), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25) //CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: button)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

    }
...
}
```

Note : i try to set on storyboard not work...

Comment: tabBarController is an UITabBarController?

Comment: let tabBarController = ESTabBarController()

Comment: maybe that is the problem i think that your TabBar controller is the navigationItem owner, can you check that, modifying the navigationItem inside your customTabBar ViewDidLoad

Comment: Any progress with this?